# Azure Ubuntu VM Not Allowing Workbench to connect to

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, azure

I have created a VM with all the specs from this post to a T:
http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/02/create-your-own-dedicated-mysql-server-for-your-azure-websites/

The one item that I have not completed "sudo ssh -fNg -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 azurevmuser@servername"  I am not sure what to put for "azurevmuser@servername"  Should this be a user on my server or a mysql?

I also I would like to run it at 3306  I believe I would just make it "3306:127.0.0.1:3306"

Also I have created the endpoints in Azure so 3306 is listed as the mysql post on private and public.

My current error in workbench is cannot not connect.  I have added my user with a wild card "%"  I believe I am just fuzzy on the port binding and is that necessary every time i need to connect a port to the outside world.

Comment: Why are you trying to add an SSH tunnel?  Do you not have other security measure in place in your environment? (i.e. Firewall, VPN, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue once and got around it by using the Standard TCP/IP over the SSH option in connection mode.

Simply provide your SSH username and password or specify a SSH key file, if you are using one instead of a password, along with your MySQL credentials.